# Discord.py and Python Schedule, never awaited for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm trying to send a message to a channel once a day at 02:39 using `Schedule` and `Threading` but I can't seem to get past
`asyncio` *"never awaited for"*.

My code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    t = Thread(target=timer)
    t.start()

async def announceShop():
    await bot.get_channel(00000000).send("test")

def timer():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(60)

schedule.every().day.at("02:39").do(bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe, announceShop)
```

Error:
`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'announceShop' was never awaited self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)`

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solution works, but it is more of a "workaround".
This solution is using aiocron which is simular to cronjob on Linux.

`pip3 install aiocron`

```py
import aiocron
@aiocron.crontab('2 3 * * *')
async def announceShop():
    await bot.get_channel(00000000).send("test")
```

Comment: This doesn't allow the @bot.event to trigger. Is there a more discord ready logic? This just has my bot hang forever without sending messages.

Comment: I'm still using this solution as of today and it does not cause any blocking, all events work as they should. Are you sure you installed aiocron and defined  it before your async function? `@aiocron.crontab('2 3 * * *')` in my case?

Comment: Yes, I have set it up the same way. I believe the discord decorator might have been causing a conflict. Once I removed it the scheduling worked, but for my use case that breaks my logic since I need the discord decorator. 

I ended up just using crontab from the command line `crontab -e`.